# If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is measurable, so are $-f$ and $kf$, for $k \ne 0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is measurable.

Please show that

i) $-f$ is measurable

ii) Let $k\in \mathbb{R}$, and $k \ne 0$. Show that $kf$ is measurable.

I am a self taught person and was wondering how the proof to this might look like. Can someone please show me. I was just reading about this and was wondering what it might look like. I might have an idea for it. Here is what I can tell by this:

In ii) is there a $k>0$, and $k<0$ that we need to show. If so, please show how you would do this.

In i) I know from looking that $f$ is measurable if $c\in \mathbb{R}$ where {$f$ is greater or equal than $c$}. Does that work here, if not please show the other way.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean in the last paragraph by: "where {f is greater or equal than c}."  That set definition doesn't mean anything. Do you when "where $\{x:f(x)\geq c\}$ is measurable"?

Comment: I edited it. Just wanted to know for i) how would you show -f is measurable?

Answer (score 1):

For part (a), notice that for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$ we have 
$$
(-f)^{-1}\big([c,\infty)\big) = \{x : -f(x) \geq c\} = \{x : f(x) \leq -c\} = f^{-1}\big((-\infty,-c])
$$ 
which is measurable since $f$ is measurable and hence $-f$ is measurable.

For part (b),  if $k > 0$, then for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$
(kf)^{-1} \big([c,\infty)\big) = \{x : kf(x) \geq c\} = \{x : f(x) \geq c/k\} = f^{-1}\big([c/k,\infty)\big)
$$
which is measurable since $f$ is measurable. If $k < 0$, then
$$
(kf)^{-1} \big([c,\infty)\big) = \{x : kf(x) \geq c\} = \{x : f(x) \leq c/k\} = f^{-1}\big((-\infty,c/k]\big)
$$
which is measurable since $f$ is. Therefore, $kf$ is measurable.